# send the data from 5 local machines to one main server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 5 databases that have the same structure, each one on a local machine and sixth one on the main server. all these five should send the data from local machines to the main server to one database.

I tried "Replication" but it seems each time i did replication it deleted the data from the main server and copy it again from the local, which keep the main server have just data from one server not all 5 .

so anyone can help me with that??, i'm using SQL server 2008 and all these machines connected with main server over VPN "IPsec"

Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest, why is it you are wanting to work with remote databases and synchronisation, rather than just look at the db on the server? I haven't seen this approach for a good number of years. I think you are going to have to look at SSIS, and specify the code to do it, as there will be a bunch of rules to look at when conflicts occur etc.

Comment: Agreed - you should let us know your actually requirements, not your potential solution. You want the local database to send data up to the main one? But not back the way? How often do you need this done? How much data?

Comment: Is there any possibility for conflicts? Does the data overlap? Can machine 1 decide that a row should be in state 1 and machine 2 that it should be in state 2, or do all machines manage their own set of non-overlapping data (including separate identity columns, if those are used)?